# Transforming dataframe with group by and include extra column values

Tags: python, pandas

Given this dataframe :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a1' , '1'], ['a2' , '2'], ['stop' , '3'], ['a2' , '4'], ['a4' , '5'], ['a5' , '6'], ['stop' , '7'], ['a6' , '8']],
                      columns=['a' , 'b'])
mask = df['a'].eq('stop')
print(df)
```

```
      a  b
0  a1    1
1  a2    2
2  stop  3
3  a2    4
4  a4    5
5  a5    6
6  stop  7
7  a6    8
```

Processing transforms the dataframe to :

```
stop = mask[::-1].idxmax()
mask = mask[:stop]
c = df['a'][:stop].copy()
c.groupby(mask.cumsum()).apply(lambda s: s[s!='stop'].tolist())
```

```
a
0    [a1, a2]    
1    [a2, a4, a5]
Name: a, dtype: object
```

where when 'stop' is encountered a new array is created that contains the previous values.

I'm attempting to create a list of tuples where column b maps to id of column a from above dataframe df. This is the expected dataframe structure upon creation:

```
0    [(a1 , 1), (a2 , 2)]    
1    [(a2 , 3), (a4 , 4), (a5 , 5)]
```

Here is my attempt so far :

```
def get_value(x) : 
    to_ret = []
    for a in x : 
        to_ret.append( (a , df[df['a'] == a]['b']))
    return to_ret


c1 = c.groupby(mask.cumsum()).apply(lambda s: s[s!='stop'].tolist())
c1.map(lambda x : get_value(x))
```

which renders :

```
a
0    [(a1, [1]), (a2, [2, 4])]           
1    [(a2, [2, 4]), (a4, [5]), (a5, [6])]
Name: a, dtype: object
```

This seems a complicated part solution to a simple problem. Is there an alternate method of transforming this dataframe ?

Comment: Should this be `[(a2 , 4), (a4 , 5), (a5 , 6)]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you could convert your dataframe to a 2-tuple Series and group *that* with something similar (`groupby` + `apply` + `tolist`) -

```
df.apply(tuple, 1)[:stop]\
  .groupby(mask.cumsum())\
  .apply(lambda s: s[s.str[0] !='stop'].tolist())

a
0             [(a1, 1), (a2, 2)]
1    [(a2, 4), (a4, 5), (a5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another appraoch

```
df['stop_loc'] = (df['a'] == 'stop').cumsum()
df_new = df[(df['a'] != 'stop') & (df['stop_loc'] != df['stop_loc'].max())].groupby('stop_loc').apply(lambda x: list(zip(x.a, x.b)))

0             [(a1, 1), (a2, 2)]
1    [(a2, 4), (a4, 5), (a5, 6)]
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems my answer is different. What did I miss?!

Comment: or did i miss something?

Comment: Your first row is different from OP's, but not your second row. Your last row should not be there because it comes after the last "stop" value.